# Как разделить на строки поток TCP данных

Tags: python, сокет, tcp

Друзья, подскажите, пожалуйста, по какому принципу разделяются данные из потока TCP для их расшифровки.

```
sock = socket.socket()
sock.connect(('ip', port))
sock.send(bytes.fromhex('cообщение серверу в hex')) 
while a == 0:
    pack = sock.recv(2048)
    print(pack)
sock.close()
```

Если сервер в ответ присылает одно сообщение, то его можно разобрать без проблем, но при определенных запросах сервер может отправить данные потоком, и в данном случае не ясно по какому алгоритму надо разбирать данные на строки, в случае с динамическим размером каждого из сообщений.

Comment: я скажу больше - даже одно сообщение может прийти от сервера в виде двух (или более) вызовов recv. Как разделить? нужен протокол - то есть, это все на совести программиста. Например, можно использовать перенос строки или другой спецсимвол. Можно кодировать сообщение в xml/json/protobuf/другой любимый вариант. А можно по старинке - в начале пакета добавлять 2-4 байта, которые указывают длину. После этого все стает элементарно

Comment: Благодарю, это точно нужно, первые 2 байта как раз размер. Выделив первое сообщение, можно отделить все остальные. Осталось понять как это делать "на лету", а не после получения данных:)

Comment: ну как - читаете размер, потом читаете данные, попросив нужный размер.